# Modified updatedBy user name in contentful

Tags: java, spring-boot, content-management-system, contentful-api

I'm creating an API in Java to create content in contentful, While running the job entries are getting created with updatedBy user as **ETL BOT**, I want to change it to custom name, so that i can filter the entries from UI as and when required.

I've below code,

```
CMAEntry entry = cmaClient.entries().fetchOne(entryId);
entry.setField("id", "en-US", id);
CMAEntry updatedEntry = cmaClient.entries().update(entry);
CMAEntry entryPublish = cmaClient.entries().fetchOne(updatedEntry.getId());
cmaClient.entries().publish(entryPublish);
```

I have seen that CMAEntry has `setSystem(CMASystem system)` and CMASystem has `CMALink updatedBy`

I can not see set method for updatedBy, Can anybody please help me how can i add custom name for updatedBy rather than **ETL BOT**.

I understand that sys.updatedBy is kinda metadata and related to auth header who is trying to create the entry, but is there any way we can modify it?